# JavaScript generated HTML-Table produces "undefined" for no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a Rich Internet Application which uses a WEB-SQL database as its source. With a simple HTML-form you could select your needed output from the database. This is triggered with a JavaScript file, that listens to the click of the "Query"-Button. All works fine, but I keep getting an "undefined" in the output - DIV. I have no idea where it comes from. Screenshot from the Output is attached. After the line "Found rows: number" there is the "undefined" statement from the script I don't get at all. Any hint is welcome!

```
$("#query").click(function() {

  var sql_string = "SELECT * from PSYCH where ";
  var selected = [];

  $('#szene input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
  });
  var selected_length = selected.length;
  sql_string = sql_string + selected[0] + " = '1'";
  for (var i = 1; i < selected_length; i++) {
    //alert(selected[i]);
    sql_string = sql_string + " AND " + selected[i] + " = '1'";
  }

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    //alert("String: "+sql_string);
    tx.executeSql(sql_string, [], function(tx, results) {

      var len = results.rows.length;
      msg = "<h3>Ergebnis</h3><p>Query: " + sql_string + "</p>";
      msg += "Found rows: " + len + "<br>";
      msg += "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>ICD10-Code</th><th>Web-Link</th></tr>";

      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        msg_loop += "<tr><td>" + results.rows.item(i).stoerung + "</td><td> " + results.rows.item(i).icd10code + "</td><td> <a href='" + results.rows.item(i).icd10_link + "' target='_blank'>Zur ICD10-Definition</a></td></tr>";

      }
      msg += msg_loop + "</table>";

      $("#output").html(function() {
        return msg
      });
    }, null);
  }, errorCB, successCB);
});
```

[image]

Comment: _Produces "undefined" for no reason_ There is always a reason. This time is appears that `results.rows.item(i).stoerung` is not defined.

Comment: Open your developer's tools (F12), go to the Sources tab, set a breakpoint on this line: `msg += "Found rows: " + len +"<br>";` and step through the code to see where it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for all hints. I ve solved it after browsing trough the code with developer's tool. It was the variable "msg_loop" wich i defined at the start of the script. It seems like this variable wasnt visible in the function "db.transaction(function (tx)". Well, i have to dive deeper into Javascript, it seems. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see `msg_loop` variable definition. So, `msg_loop +=` will not work. Define it before use, before `for` cycle: `var msg_loop = ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you iterate over the results in `for` you need to access the elements like:
`results.rows[i]`